# Does Material material = (new Location(w,x,y,z)).getBlock().getType() work?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I want to define a ton of block materials, but I don't want it to take up so much space in my code. So, I thought that maybe this would work?

```java
Material material = (new Location(w,x,y,z)).getBlock().getType()
```

Does that get the material of the position w, x, y, z(w is world)?

Comment: Yes, that will get the material but what are you trying to achieve? Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can also write a method that does that code for you if you don't want to repeat yourself.

Comment: I want to define a ton of block materials(there's no pattern, it's not a cube size or anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided in the question is the same; although more concise, as:

```java
Location location = new Location(w, x, y, z);
Block block = location.getBlock();
Material material = block.getType();
```

Where `new Location(...` creates a new instance of the [`Location`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Location.html) class which has a [`getBlock()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Location.html#getBlock()) method. This method will return an instance of the [`Block`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/Block.html) interface which from there you can use [`getType()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/block/Block.html#getType()) which returns an instance of [`Material`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/Material.html).

So yes, as long as your world and the coordinates of the block exist, it will get the material at the specified position.

You can read more on the `new` keyword [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html).

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, I want to know if my code works and detects the block at the specified location (w,x,y,z), because I am not too familiar with objects and the 'new' word.

Comment: *not detects, stores as a variable.

Comment: Thanks! This has reduced the number of lines I needed a LOT!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it answered the question :)